# How to get Windows 10 search from menu to open in seperate window

Tags: windows-10, search

It's hard to describe but the behavior of a Windows 10 search that is started from the start menu is wrong. The results are only displayed in the start menu itself and not a separate window. It does not give me the option to view the results externally. This is bad because I like seeing the list details of a search that return multiple items, such as the created date.

Also modifiers like "kind:picture" or "type:document" don't work and no matches are found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Windows Search from the task bar integrates found items in the Search window. That is the way it works.

You can use instead Search from Windows File Explorer (top right of the Explorer window).

Then search results show up as a list in File Explorer that you can browse.

> I like seeing the list details of a search that return multiple items,
> such as the created date.

You can do that with the File Explorer Search. You can choose columns you wish to see in File Explorer options.

[image: File Explorer Search]

From the Task Bar search, results are integrated.

[image]

Comment: This still didn't work in most cases. In `indexing options` C: was missing and only a couple of specific folders had been indexed. I'm waiting for indexing to complete now.

Comment: Perhaps rebuilding the index will help. I use the File Explorer approach frequently and it works well. I have a search index of about 175,000 items.  Also you can use this on a non-indexed folder and the results are the same - just takes a bit longer.

Comment: It seems to be working now but `kind:document` still doesn't work from the start menu

Comment: The Search results from the Start Menu are integrated into the Start Menu as I said in my answer. There is no way I know to change that except to use File Explorer. So I think I have explained how to get separate window search results.